# How do you disable padding in cells?

Tags: html, html-table

In a table how can you disable the padding between tr's and td's? I have tried setting padding to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the border-collapse and border-spacing.  Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ppxmqrr/1/) that has an example.

include the following css in your code, or put it in a class and assign that class to your table

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0; 
}
```

[Here's a good writeup](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/) of border-collapse

[Here's a writeup](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp) of border-spacing